# how to disable sessions in php

Tags: php, session

From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php), one of the possible statuses is [PHP_SESSION_DISABLED](http://php.net/manual/en/session.constants.php#constant.php-session-disabled).

How do you disable sessions in PHP?

Answer (score 3):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.installation.php):

> Session support is enabled in PHP by default. If you would not like to
>   build your PHP with session support, you should specify the
>   **--disable-session** option to configure.

Comment: Is that the only way to do it? Would that flag remove all the session_* functions? If so then session_status() wouldn't work when --disable-session had been called. Are there any ways pre-5.4.0 (When session_status was introduced) that could be used to see if sessions were disabled thusly?

Comment: `$session_support = is_callable('session_start');`